# BPEL Assign a list and display it in the output

Tags: eclipse, assign, bpel, apache-ode

I'm using BPEL Designer with eclipse and ode apache as a bpel server. 
I just want do a simple assign of list from the input to the output. In oracle assign have a copy rule that could change from "copy" to "copyList" to do the assign for a list, but I can't found that option with ode.

Any help, I'm new with BPEL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the concrete structures it is difficult to help. But have a look at [ODE's XPath Extensions](http://ode.apache.org/extensions/xpath-extensions.html), in particular `insert-after`.